# reCaptcha not working on Sign Up page

Tags: php, recaptcha

I run a NFL pick em site and lately have been getting a lot of spam. My sign up page just throws the info from the sign up form in to a database, but I can't figure out how to get reCaptcha working.

I have the captcha showing up and everything, but currently it does not matter if you fill out the captcha or not... I've even typed random letters in it and it still went through. So basically you can sign up for my site and ignore the captcha all together.

Here is my code:

(I couldn't get the code to format properly on here...)

[Signup.php-Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/iyDQKptS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fail validation you are just filling an errors array and continuing with your script.

```
// begin: reCAPTCHA - VALIDATE
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                        $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                        $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid captcha';
}
// end: reCAPTCHA - VALIDATE
```

You need to wrap everything after this point in an `else` block, otherwise you just fill your `$errors` array and happily proceed with the rest of your page. You aren't even using your `$errors` array later.

Comment: Well... that was easy. I knew I was missing something simple.